# Language and Admin Interface

Tags: multilingual, admin-pages

We have a client that wants to use Spanish as the default language when they login to the admin interface. I added Spanish to the core and master database. Then I set a user's defaults to it but when they login all of the words are blank. I saw that if I go into the core database and add versions for Spanish and update the name for an item like "Preview". Then it would show up.

Do I have to go to every item in the core database and add a Spanish version and update the display name for the admin interface to show in Spanish? Is there an easier way or a package I can download instead?

It is on Sitecore 8.2 Update 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore does not offer a Spanish language pack for the Sitecore client. Only the following are available:

[image]

Comment: This helped. I wish they had Spanish but looking at the instructions for importing the languages they have. I was able to export Spanish out of an old 6.4 we had and import that into our 8.2. Not everything is there but it is miles ahead of having nothing.